# Cуществует ли слово ФУНЦИКЛИРОВАТЬ?

Tags: этимология

Существует ли слово `фунциклирует` или `фунциклировать`? Если существует, то что оно означает?

Comment: "функционировать", в ироническо-жаргонном преломлении

Answer (score 2):

См. **Словарь русского арго** (http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_15039 ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]